# Issue in Kohana Query

Tags: orm, model, kohana

I'm facing an issue in my query.Kindly help me to sort the issue (I’m newbie in Kohana Framework)

```
$posts->select(array(DB::expr('( SELECT COUNT(id_visit) FROM `oc2_visits` WHERE `oc2_post`.`id_post` = `oc2_visits`.`id_ad` AND `oc2_visits`.controller = "Blog" GROUP BY `oc2_visits`.`id_ad`)'), 'hits'));

        //we sort all ads with few parameters
        $posts = $posts->order_by('created','desc')
                        ->limit($pagination->items_per_page)
                        ->offset($pagination->offset)
                        ->limit(Theme::get('num_home_blog_posts', 4))->cached()
                        ->find_all();
```

As you can see 'hits' is property set at DB:expr(). In my view I'm trying to access the $posts->hits; property. Then the issue appearing hits property doesn't exists.
[image]

Image is attached, Please help I'm not expert in kohana framework.

Comment: Let's see your "Post" model class file. You are missing the 'hits' field in there according to the error message

Comment: FYI when I started using Kohana in version 2.0 I used to use ORM a lot but then later found it to be too restrictive. I abandoned ORM and am now using the direct approach to the DB instance like: $query = DB::select('*')->from('oc2_visits)->where('id','=',1); $shipping = $query->as_object()->execute()->current();

Answer (score 0):

Try this non-ORM approach:

```
$query = DB::select(array(DB::Expr('COUNT(v.id_visit)'), 'hits'))
    ->from(array('oc2_visits', 'v'))
    ->join(array('oc2_post', 'p'), 'INNER')
        ->on('p.id_post', '=', 'v.id_ad')
    ->where('v.controller', '=', 'Blog')
    ->group_by('v.id_ad')
    ->order_by('v.created','desc')
    ->limit($pagination->items_per_page) //why 2 limit statements? Oversight?
    ->offset($pagination->offset)
    ->limit(Theme::get('num_home_blog_posts', 4));
$posts = $query->execute();
//Or if you want objects use:
$posts = $query->as_object()->execute();
```